# How to convert a List(of Long) into a string array? (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert a List (of Long) into a string array.

Reason: it's a list of database IDs and I want to make a comma delimited string to pass into a stored proc.

I tried this:

```
Dim commaDelimitedList As String = String.Join(",", itemIDList.Cast(Of String)().ToArray)
```

but I'm clearly not using the Cast correctly since it throws an exception:
*System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'..*

Is there a way to get Cast working for this, or am I stuck with ConvertAll and a delegate function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use LINQ this will do what you want:

```
Dim commaDelimitedList  As String = String.Join(",", itemIDList.Select(Function(itemID) itemID.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: Perfect thanks - I came to the same conclusion 30 seconds later!

Answer (score 3):

Can't cast - unless you can LINQ, you have to convert each int into a string so you have an array of strings 
   CLR 2.0 has a ConvertAll() method that will do that...

```
string s =  String.Join(",",
              l1.ConvertAll<string>(delegate(int i) 
                 { return i.ToString(); }).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

I realised that I could use ConvertAll with a lambda function to keep it all nicely on one line, so I think this is my solution:

```
  Dim commaDelimitedList As String = _
String.Join(",", itemIDList.ConvertAll(New Converter(Of Long, String)(Function(i As Long) CStr(i))).ToArray)
```